# Why am I getting an 'expected identifier before (' when attempting to refer to values within struct

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, reference

I can do `free(STRUCTPOINTER->thing1->thing2)`

but I can't do `free((*STRUCTPOINTER).(*thing1).thing2)`  (Expected identifier before ( token. For  (*thing1

nor can I do `free((*STRUCTPOINTER).thing1.thing2)` Error, (*temporary)-> is a pointer, did you mean to use '->' ?

I am used to writing my code and referring to things in (*this).format. Is this possible for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Why do you rather need this expression: free((*STRUCTPOINTER).(*thing1).thing2)?

Comment: You would need to write `free((*(*ptr).thing1).thing2` if you're insane enough not to use the arrow notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I noted (more or less) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73596918/why-am-i-getting-an-expected-identifier-before-when-attempting-to-refer-to-v#comment129964405_73596918):

If you're insane enough not to use the arrow notation,
you would need to use:

```
free((*(*ptr).thing1).thing2);
```

I'm sorry, but I don't like shouting as loudly as `STRUCTPOINTER` requires, especially as it isn't a macro; I'm using `ptr` instead.

- `*ptr` is the structure that `ptr` points to
- `(*ptr).thing1` is the member of the structure, which is a pointer to a structure, so you need
- `*(*ptr).thing1` to dereference the structure, and
- `(*(*ptr).thing1).thing2` to access the element

The arrow notation was invented for a good reason — this is it!  It is hard to get the alternative correct.